# How To Make An Advance Poll Command Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hey So Im making an poll command concept but i cant figure out how make it
My Concept

```
author : >poll
bot : (embed that says you must pick the option 1)
author : say the option 1
bot : (embed that says you must pick the option 2)
author : say the option 2
bot: ( message that says we must react to reaction number 1 or number 2 )
```

Do anyone know my concept ?

My Curret Code

```
}else if (command =="poll"){
    const pollbase = new D.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription('What Is Your First Option')
    .setAuthor('The Bot')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('The Bot')
    .setColor(color)
   msg.channel,send(pollbase)
}
```

i have no clue what to do next
can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages):

```js
const pollbase = new D.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription("What Is Your First Option")
  .setAuthor("The Bot")
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter("The Bot")
  .setColor(color);
msg.channel.send(pollbase);

// create message filter
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === msg.author.id;

msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 }).then((collected) => {
  // do whatever you want with the next message sent
  console.log(
    `${message.author.username} responded: ${collected.first().content}`
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your `msg.channel,send(pollbase)` part needs to be `msg.channel.send(pollbase)`.
you put a comma before 'send' instead of a period